# Understanding how predefined methods work

Tags: objective-c, methods

I am a novice in Objective-C and I am trying to understand how pre-defined methods work. I went through the documentation of XCode and the *.h files where the method is defined. However I am eager to read the *.m file or any other document that can help me understand how the method works.

For instance - `isEqualToString:(NSString *)` checks if two strings (of the type NSString) are equal or not. I am not satisfied with this description. I am eager to see how the method works internally or what is the algorithm it follows. Where can I find this information?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could use the debugger, there you can observe the method at assembler level.

Comment: If I dare comment (/rant, but hopefully politely): if you're not satisfied with the description then you're not really going to be able to get on in a closed source object-oriented environment. The documentation doesn't specify the algorithm used because it doesn't intend to bind itself to an algorithm. Such methods may change at any time in any version of the OS without notification either in advance or after the fact. Objects are sovereign and second guessing how they store and process their data isn't productive and usually isn't even reliable.

Answer (score 1):

- isEqualToString:(NSString *) is a method defined in the NSString class. Apple provides you with the framework, but they do not provide the implementation of those methods. Therefore, you can't see the source behind the standard framework's libraries.

Edit: you can create a binary and use this app to check the assembly code: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hopper-disassembler/id422856039?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a lot of the implementation (`.m`) files for Apple's frameworks aren't provided publicly. You have a couple alternatives:

1. As Matthias suggested in a comment, use the debugger and inspect the assembler code generated for that method.
2. Browse through the repositories for the [GNUstep](http://gnustep.org/) project, which has some equivalents to Apple classes.